# Using different style on segments of a plot

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, color, style

Is it possible to plot a function with two different colors?
To illustrate, let's have:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

which plots a curve. And I would like it to be red from `{x,0,π}` and blue `{x,π,2π}`? I found the [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) but I am not sure that it is capable of this, as the documentation says that it is given the y coordinate for `Plot`.

Even more, (actually this is the final goal), instead of different colours, I would like different styles, so let's say a solid line from `{x,0,π}` and dashed line from `{x,π,2π}`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**MeshShading**

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, MeshFunctions -> {# &}, 
 Mesh -> {{Pi/2}}, MeshShading -> {Red, Directive[Dashed, Blue]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Two piecewise functions**

```
Plot[{ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], x <= Pi], 
  ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], x >= Pi]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red], Directive[Thick, Dashed, Blue]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Post - processing**

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]] /. 
 Line[x_] :> (With[{xx = (Pick[x, #[[1]] <= Pi & /@ x, #] & /@ {True, 
         False})}, {Line@xx[[1]], Dashed, Blue, Line@xx[[2]]}])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**ColorFunction**

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[x <= Pi, Red, Blue]], 
 PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

One more trick is to use `Show`

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, Pi, 2 Pi}], PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `ColorFunction` with `Function`.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][y]]]
```

[image]

A rather quack way can be dividing you plots into segments with distinct style and combine them together.

```
 plot[l_, dl_] := Plot[Sin[x], {x, l 2 Pi, (l + dl) 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Hue[l], PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, All}]
 dl = 0.01;
 Show[plot[#, # + dl] & /@ Range[0, 1 - dl, dl]]
```

[image]