# How to color/highlight pieces of a plot

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I'm trying to explain the fact that a Brownian motion has independent increments by highlighting disjoint segments of a sample path of a Brownian motion. So, given a sample path of a (standard) Brownian motion

```
ListLinePlot[RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 1, 0.01}]]
```

how does one color the trajectory (for example) from 0.1 to 0.3 red, and from 0.5 to 0.8 blue?

Comment: related/ posssible duplicate Q/A: [Using different style on segments of a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114288/125)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 1, 0.01}],
     Mesh -> {{0.1,0.3,0.5,0.8}}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#1 &},
     MeshShading -> {Black,Red, Black,Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much!